# Connecting two computers over LAN while contending with DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, lan, dhcp

Please excuse this question if this is on the wrong stack or if it is considered to be looking for service recommendations. I tried asking this over at Network Engineering however they don't deal with anything over OSI layer-4 and directed me here.

I will be hosting a headless server (though, acting as another client) on my Universities LAN. I would like to be able to SSH into it from my laptop however this network is DHCP based so either or both could change IPs upon the networks discretion. How would I keep my laptop informed of the server's IP address if it changes? I was thinking using python to detect when the server changes IP addresses and then using an email client to email itself the new IP address and then have my laptop check this inbox automagicaly for IP changes. This would work but it seems like a very round about way of doing things and requires quite a bit more effort than there seems to need to be. Any other options I could try? Note that I can't set it to be a static IP as I don't have access to the DHCP server and I'd rather not spam the network with a bunch of extra packets just trying to find the server.

Comment: If your interested in buying a cloud computing instance like a DigitalOcean droplet then you can use openVPN.  Place openVPN server on the droplet and openVPN client on the headless “server”.   If you want to do it for free, I’d take the general idea you’ve got, but have python call a pushover.net API to send a notification to my phone, I’d parse that manually if I needed to login.  There is a pushover desktop client, not sure if you can use it to automate the laptop end.  Pushover is much faster (and more reliable) than email.

Comment: @Tyson I have definitely thought about that (Hak5 is great) but I really don't want to be deliberately bypassing the firewall if I can help it. I'd like to keep my nose clean. That was going to be an option for running this as an actual server with a few online services however administration isn't keen on the idea because this network is meant for client traffic, not server hosting. And thus it will be running as gigantic client, probably used for machine learning. I just want an easy way to connect to it while on campus and I dislike TeamViewer. Pushover seems more like what Im looking for

Comment: @Tyson I took a look into pushover and it looks like just what I need, no mucking about with bouncing emails all over the place. And though you can't natively use the desktop client in automation, there is a client API available and a mixture of the two is perfect. Thanks for the recommend

Comment: I’ve used pushover for like a year and a half with my home automation system, it just always works and it’s very fast.  The notification arrives instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DNS Name for the headless server, instead of the IP.

This is assuming that DNS is enabled on this network.

Comment: Another question entirely, but how would I be able to tell if DNS is enabled without completely installing and configuring the server.

Comment: @Bobser: DNS support is a feature of the LAN infrasructure (usually specifically of the DHCP server) if your headless server used DHCP it will tell the DHCP server what hostname is configured into the headless server and the DHCP service will update the DNS service so that clients can use that name to reach the headless server.

Comment: if it's on the network, the DHCP should advertise the server address to the connecting client. if you have a machine on the network already, check if a DNS server is listed. the address you then use is <localmachinename>.domain

Comment: Using ifconfig and nslookup to check out two computers IPs, it doesn't look like host names are publicly assigned. This is more like I'm behind a router but my laptop and server could change IP whenever there is a reconnect.

Comment: BobserLuck - can you post the ifconfig screens for both machines?

Answer (score 0):

@Stese's answer is good.

A good way to find out if your network assigns a DNS name to your IP is to find out your IP, then do an `nslookup` on your IP (works on most OSes):

> `nslookup 10.X.X.X`

This is called a "reverse lookup" and will tell you the DNS name if one exists.

Your network may not provide a name, or it's possible the DNS name assigned might contain your IP address or otherwise be uniquely generated.

If this is true, then you need a dynamic DNS provider.  Dyndns used to be a good free one in the past, another current provider is noip.com.  There's others out there.  You will need to make an account, then run an "update client" on your server that will basically check for IP changes and communicate back to the service, which then updates the public DNS record it maintains.

> I was thinking using python to detect when the server changes IP addresses and then using an email client to email itself the new IP address and then have my laptop check this inbox automagicaly for IP changes. This would work but it seems like a very round about way of doing things and requires quite a bit more effort than there seems to need to be.

Don't rule this out if for example your university blocks noip.com for some reason.

Comment: University networks usually assign private non-routable (10.x.x.x) IPs, which is why OP is asking.

Comment: I mean, No-IP is great and I've used it before for a home network but unfortunately these computers are behind a firewall and not routable from the outside web. I know there are ways to get around firewalls from the inside (reverse VPN comes to mind) but that's not my intention. Only for updating the local IP addresses on the sub domain of the network I'm using. And it doesn't look like this domain assigns names for nslookup on the network.

Comment: Yeah don't know why I assumed you'd have a forwarded port on your university's routing infrastructure.  You need a system outside of the network to build a VPN tunnel to.  You can also look into running a Tor hidden service - since it starts by making an outgoing connection to Tor, it will work.  But you have to have Tor running to use it.